# Appropriate values for negative and positive infinity in MS Excel

Tags: excel, xlsx

I am implementing a parser for MS Excel document [.xlsx files] 
To understand, how infinity values are stored inside the Excel, I unzipped one of my Excel file and I found below in one of the sheet: 
[image]

Here, you can see, the infinity value is stored as a text **"INF"**

But, I want to know what is exact value Excel uses to represent infinity values.
In my parser, instead of parsing text "INF", I want to parse it as actual infinity boundary values.

Could you please help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was wrong about my analysis. 
Excel does not have infinity value. It has its upper and lower boundary values for number
(1.7976931348623158e+308 and -1.7976931348623158e+308)

The issue was in my parser. I have implemented my Excel parser in OCaml language. OCaml's float_of_string function treats the string "INF" as infinity value.

Anyways, this was an issue from my parser side.

Thank you.